# In Lift, send the ID of tag, along with a function result

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala, lift

I have this code and it works:

```
def render =
  "#liftScript" #> Script(JqJsCmds.JqOnLoad(
    JqJE.Jq("#plus") ~> JqJE.JqClick(
      js.JE.AnonFunc(SHtml.jsonCall(
        JE.Call("myJsFnuc"), plus  _
      ))
    ) &
    JqJE.Jq("#minus") ~> JqJE.JqClick(
      js.JE.AnonFunc(SHtml.jsonCall(
        JE.Call("myJsFunc"), minus  _
      ))
    )
  ).cmd)
```

If I were writing my own JavaScript, I'd do it like this:

```
$("#minus, #plus").click(function() {
  myCallback(myJsFunc(), $(this).attr("id"));
  // Or, if my callback must take no more than one argument:
  myCallback([myJsFunc(), $(this).attr("id")]);
});
```

I've tried to do this with Lift, but I have not come close to succeeding. I tried a curried callback like:

```
def myCallBack(caller: String)(data: JValue) = ...
```

But I got two problems with that.

- First, the "caller" argument was only set of the first call, which I'll admit I did not expect.
- And also, its value was always `jQuery("this").attr("id")`, in other words it was the JavaScript code, and not its evaluated value.

Usually, when I get something like that wrong with Lift, it's because I'm doing it in a way that's much harder than what I need to do. Does anyone know how do this right? There must be a way to pass the value of a caller element's ID to Lift.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to create a custom event! (This took me a while to figure out.)

With this extra JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#plus, #minus').click(function () {
        $('body').trigger('customEvent', [[myJsFunc(), $(this).attr('id')]]);
    });
});
```

I can then do this in Lift:

```
def render =
"#liftScript" #> Script(JqJsCmds.JqOnLoad(
  JqJE.Jq("body") ~> JE.JsFunc("on", JString("customEvent"),
    JE.AnonFunc("event, value", SHtml.jsonCall(
      JE.JsRaw("value"), processData  _
    ))
  )
).cmd)
```

Done and done. Phfew. That was hard to figure out, but easy to do.